# Persisting Design Time Properties in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, persistence, designer

I am writing a stylable control for Windows Forms. By stylable I mean the user has greater control over the appearance of the `Control` than the standard `BackColor`, `ForeColor` etc. The following code has been simplified to illustrate the problem

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class BrushProperties : Component
{
    public Color[] GradientColors { get; set; }
    public Single[] GradientPositions { get; set; }
    public Single GradientAngle { get; set; }
}

[ToolboxItem(false)]
public class Style : Component
{
    public BrushProperties Background { get; set; }
    public BrushProperties Foreground { get; set; }

    public Style()
    {
         this.Background = new BrushProperties();
         this.Foreground = new BrushProperties();
    }
}

public class StyleControl : Control
{
    public Style Style { get; set; }

    public StyleControl()
    {
        this.Style = new Style();
    }
}
```

When I am in the designer I can see all of the properties of `Style` and all of the properties of each `BrushProperties` instance. I can change the values as well, but the moment I build/run the project, the values I've assigned to the properties disappear. What does my code require in order to persist the property values that are specified at design time?

Comment: Do you really need to base the `BrushProperties` and `Style` classes from `Component`? If you're going for design-time support, you could remove the `Component` from inheritance chain and replace it with an [ExpandableObjectConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter.aspx) atteibute instead.

Comment: @IronGeek - I actually did this in the end! I didn't know about ExpandableObjectConverter prior to asking this question, but it worked a treat!

Comment: @IronGeek would you care to add this as an answer so I can accept?

Comment: I've posted my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to have a design-time support, then you don't need to base all your classes from the [`Component`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) object. Instead you could decorate your classes with the [`ExpandableObjectConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.expandableobjectconverter.aspx) attribute.

The `PropertyGrid` will use the `ExpandableObjectConverter` attribute to determine whether if it should expand the properties of an object or not.

Example:

```
[ToolboxItem(false)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class BrushProperties
{
  public Color[] GradientColors { get; set; }
  public Single[] GradientPositions { get; set; }
  public Single GradientAngle { get; set; }
}

[ToolboxItem(false)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter))]
public class Style
{
  public BrushProperties Background { get; set; }
  public BrushProperties Foreground { get; set; }

  public Style()
  {
    this.Background = new BrushProperties();
    this.Foreground = new BrushProperties();
  }
}
```